# Exclude URL from contributing pageviews to Google Analytic's reports

Tags: google-analytics, filtering, advanced-segments

I want a specific URL to not contribute pageviews Google Analytics default reports, but I don't want to use a filter because as I understand it, once I filter out the data, It's lost forever and I can't consult it in the future.

Applying segmentation is no good because it filters out entire sessions or users who visited this URL.

So what's the preferred/recommended way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new view with a filter applied.

You should, as a best practice, have three core views:

1. a "Raw" view, where there are no filters applied at all. I typically replicate all goals in this view as well.
2. a "Test" view to try out new filters and goals, etc. With this test view you can create a filter to filter out the unwanted URL.
3. a "Master" view for your main reporting data. If the filter works in the test view, then you can apply it to the master view.

You can create as many views as you need, so you could have one that specifically filters out the unwanted URL. This way, you can don't have to worry about losing data just because you applied a filter, because you'll always have your Raw view as a sort of backup of all your data.

Answer (score 1):

You should disable google analytics for **that Page Only** putting the following code **before** the Google Analytics Tracking Code in the `<head>` section

```
<script>
if(window.location.href==='http://www.example.com/example-page/'){
  window['ga-disable-UA-XXXXXX-X'] = true;
}
</script>
```

Where UA-XXXXXX-X is your website Google Analytics tracking ID, Remember to set your page URL.